# Running Exiftool in Alpine Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, exif, exiftool

I have been struggling with the installation of Exiftool for my AWS ECS Container. I'm using `python:3.7-alpine3.13` as my base image and successfully added `exiftool` and `perl-image-exiftool` by adding `RUN apk add exiftool perl-image-exiftool` to my Dockerfile.

On my Mac all I had to do was `brew install exiftool` to get it to work.

Although the code works in my local developement and the build process works for my container I still get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'exiftool': 'exiftool'`

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: what do you get when you execute `which exiftool`? `exiftool not found` or a path?

Comment: Nothing was being returned, I found a solution by changing the line where I was installing, but I'm not sure why it made a difference...
Anyway, now, when I run `which exiftool` it works

Comment: please post an answer with the `RUN` line that fixed it for future googlers arriving in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why it worked or made a difference, but moving where the installation of the library was happening fixed the issue

Original

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev \
    libressl-dev libffi-dev exiftool
```

Fixed

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev \
    libressl-dev libffi-dev
RUN apk add exiftool
```

If anybody know why that would make a difference I would be happy to learn about it!